# How to include headers in connection between React client and AWS Websocket?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, aws-lambda, frontend

I am developing a Front-end using Reactjs. I need to make a connection to an AWS Websocket. The required headers of the websocket are the following:

- Authorization: "Bearer TOKEN"
- terminalId: "TERMINAL ID".

I have decided to use socket.io client (socket.io-client). To make the connection I have tried the following code structure:

```
 const socket = io( URL, {
        path: "/dev",
        transports: ["false","websocket"],
        transportOptions: {
            extraHeaders: {
                Authorization: "Bearer TOKEN",
                terminalId: "ID DE TERMINAL"
            }
        },

    });
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("socket disconnected");
    });
```

I have tried sending the extraHeaders out of transportOption but the server log continues to show that the connection does not have the headers attached.

**What could be happening?
Is there another client that allows to attach the headers?**

PS: The websocket works correctly in wscat using the -H flags to attach the headers.

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-extraHeaders) it mentions custom headers will not be appended when using `websocket`  as the transport which you seem to be using.

Browsers WebSocket don't seem to support setting custom headers so you have two options. One would be to pass the auth through the cookies which get passed along in the socket. The second would be to handle this in the backend